# JVM Getting crashed in Compiler Thread PhaseIdealLoop::Dominators

Tags: java, linux, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

My JVM is getting crashed randomly at below method

`(PhaseIdealLoop::Dominators)` always. Java Version :

> - java version "1.7.0_10"
> - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_10-b18)
> - Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9001c60871, pid=26567, tid=140256146601728
#
# JRE version: 7.0_10-b18
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x461871]  PhaseIdealLoop::Dominators()+0x641
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f8ffc3b4800):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=26583, stack(0x00007f8fedbbb000,0x00007f8fedcbc000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000028

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000002, RCX=0x0000000000000003, RDX=0x00007f8f88d7a490
RSP=0x00007f8fedcb70b0, RBP=0x00007f8fedcb7160, RSI=0x00007f8fedcb8860, RDI=0x00007f8f8b7997f0
R8 =0x00007f8f8b7913c0, R9 =0x00007f8f8b791410, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x00007f8f8b7d9260
R12=0x0000000000000002, R13=0x0000000000000003, R14=0x00007f8f88d7a458, R15=0x00007f8ffc3ae200
RIP=0x00007f9001c60871, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010297, CSGSFS=0x000000000000e033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f8fedcb70b0)
0x00007f8fedcb70b0:   00007f8ffc3ae200 00007f8f8b7826e0
0x00007f8fedcb70c0:   00007f8fedcb8860 00007f8f8b782690
0x00007f8fedcb70d0:   00007f8f888bc720 000015ad01f3d707
0x00007f8fedcb70e0:   00007f8f456be2a0 00007f8f456de110
0x00007f8fedcb70f0:   00007f8f456de110 00007f8ffc3ae200
0x00007f8fedcb7100:   00007f8fedcb8860 00007f8f8b791410
0x00007f8fedcb7110:   00007f90024bd650 00007f8ffc3ae200
0x00007f8fedcb7120:   0000000000000400 00007f8f8ba7c490
0x00007f8fedcb7130:   00007f8fedcb7160 00007f8f8935bae0
0x00007f8fedcb7140:   00007f8ffc3ae200 00007f8fedcb8860
0x00007f8fedcb7150:   00007f90024d5cc0 00007f8ffc3ae200
0x00007f8fedcb7160:   00007f8fedcb7410 00007f9001e8b95c
0x00007f8fedcb7170:   00007f8f8ef7f390 00007f8fedcb73c0
0x00007f8fedcb7180:   00007f8fedcb7190 00017f900206e9fd
0x00007f8fedcb7190:   00007f8fedcb8880 000000020207275b
0x00007f8fedcb71a0:   00007f8f89353ae0 00007f8f89353b30
0x00007f8fedcb71b0:   00007f8f8935bac8 00007f8ffc3ae200
0x00007f8fedcb71c0:   00007f8fedcb71d0 00007f900206e9fd
0x00007f8fedcb71d0:   00007f8fedcb7230 00007f9001c52328
0x00007f8fedcb71e0:   00007f8f8dca2ca0 0000000000000000
0x00007f8fedcb71f0:   00007f8f895926f8 00007f8f895926f8
0x00007f8fedcb7200:   00005754edcb7260 0000000000000000
0x00007f8fedcb7210:   00007f8f895926f8 00007f8f882fbd20
0x00007f8fedcb7220:   00007f90024d5cc0 0000000000000005
0x00007f8fedcb7230:   00007f8fa4157ae8 00007f9002070291
0x00007f8fedcb7240:   00007f8f890e3ce8 00007f8f8ef7d310
0x00007f8fedcb7250:   00007f8fedcb7270 00007f9002070dc8
0x00007f8fedcb7260:   00007f8fedcb7280 00007f9001f18539
0x00007f8fedcb7270:   00007f8f0000007d 0000000000001000
0x00007f8fedcb7280:   0000000000000200 0000000000040040
0x00007f8fedcb7290:   0000000000000001 0000000000000008
0x00007f8fedcb72a0:   0000000000000040 0000103000004002 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f9001c60871)
0x00007f9001c60851:   ff bb 01 00 00 00 66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 49
0x00007f9001c60861:   8b 56 08 89 d8 48 8b b5 60 ff ff ff 48 8b 04 c2
0x00007f9001c60871:   8b 40 28 3b 46 28 0f 82 73 01 00 00 48 8b 85 60
0x00007f9001c60881:   ff ff ff 4c 89 f6 48 8b b8 70 09 00 00 48 81 c7 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
RDX=0x00007f8f88d7a490 is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f8fedcb70b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f8ffc3b4800
RBP=0x00007f8fedcb7160 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f8ffc3b4800
RSI=0x00007f8fedcb8860 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f8ffc3b4800
RDI=0x00007f8f8b7997f0 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00007f8f8b7913c0 is an unknown value
R9 =0x00007f8f8b791410 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x00007f8f8b7d9260 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
R14=0x00007f8f88d7a458 is an unknown value
R15=0x00007f8ffc3ae200 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00007f8fedbbb000,0x00007f8fedcbc000],  sp=0x00007f8fedcb70b0,  free space=1008k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x461871]  PhaseIdealLoop::Dominators()+0x641
V  [libjvm.so+0x68c95c]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_and_optimize(bool, bool)+0x41c
V  [libjvm.so+0x3bb9c9]  Compile::Optimize()+0x709
V  [libjvm.so+0x3bcdfc]  Compile::Compile(ciEnv*, C2Compiler*, ciMethod*, int, bool, bool)+0xdbc
V  [libjvm.so+0x32eb62]  C2Compiler::compile_method(ciEnv*, ciMethod*, int)+0x142
V  [libjvm.so+0x3c1d73]  CompileBroker::invoke_compiler_on_method(CompileTask*)+0x323
V  [libjvm.so+0x3c2edd]  CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop()+0x43d
V  [libjvm.so+0x8650c8]  JavaThread::thread_main_inner()+0xc8
V  [libjvm.so+0x865218]  JavaThread::run()+0x138
V  [libjvm.so+0x746c00]  java_start(Thread*)+0x100


Current CompileTask:
C2:3311290   77 % ! com.test::methodName @ 1846
```

Comment: Your version of Java is too old. There was [a number of bugfixes](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22PhaseIdealLoop%20crash%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC) in PhaseIdealLoop since then.

Comment: We have byte code compiled on 1.6 and we are running on 1.7_10. Will this cause any issues??

Comment: Backward compatibility is not an issue. You can run any previous class version on up-to-date Java. Java 7 is no longer supported, consider updating to Java 8.

Comment: I have seen bugs at below link. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/issues/?jql=text%20~%20%22PhaseIdealLoop%20crash%22%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC.    These are related to Open JDK. Is it applicable on Sun JRE as well.

Comment: Yes. Sun/Oracle JDK is based on OpenJDK.